# Trouble getting the right website data into excel

Tags: html, vba, excel, web-scraping

I wanted tomake a list of my LEGO collection by entering the set numbers in the first column, and having excel look them up online and fill in the details like set name, brick count, ...

This is my code:

```
Option Explicit  
Sub BrickLinkDataExtraction()

    Dim x As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer

    For i = 5 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        IE.navigate "https://brickset.com/sets/" & Cells(RowIndex:=i, columnindex:=1).Value
        IE.Visible = False

        Do
            DoEvents
        Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE 'hier moet ik zeggen "tot rijen vol zijn", zoiets? IsEmpty(Range("i+1" & "A"))

        Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
        Set Doc = IE.document
        Dim NAME As String
        NAME = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("dd")(1).innerText)
        Dim THEME As String
        THEME = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("dd")(4).innerText)
        Dim YEAR As String
        YEAR = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("dd")(6).innerText)
        Dim BRICKS As String
        BRICKS = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("dd")(8).innerText)
        Dim MINIFIGS As String
        MINIFIGS = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("dd")(9).innerText)

        If IsEmpty(Cells(RowIndex:=i, columnindex:=2)) Then
            Cells(RowIndex:=i, columnindex:=2).Value = NAME
        End If

        If IsEmpty(Cells(RowIndex:=i, columnindex:=3)) Then
            Cells(RowIndex:=i, columnindex:=3).Value = BRICKS
        End If

        If IsEmpty(Cells(RowIndex:=i, columnindex:=4)) Then
            Cells(RowIndex:=i, columnindex:=4).Value = MINIFIGS
        End If

        If IsEmpty(Cells(RowIndex:=i, columnindex:=5)) Then
            Cells(RowIndex:=i, columnindex:=5).Value = THEME
        End If

        If IsEmpty(Cells(RowIndex:=i, columnindex:=6)) Then
            Cells(RowIndex:=i, columnindex:=6).Value = YEAR
        End If

    Next

    IE.Quit

    Cells.Columns.AutoFit

End Sub
```

This works fine, until the code reaches a set that doesn't have the  tags in the same order, or not using minifigs. Then I get the wrong info in my spreadsheet.

How can I specify I need the  beloning to the  "name", instead of specifying the second, fifth, ... ?

So for example https://brickset.com/sets/10224 works as intended; but https://brickset.com/sets/10262 enters the original retail price in the minifigs column.

Also, is there a way to optimize the code so it doesn't take as long to run?

Comment: You don't need to keep specifying RowIndex:=i, columnindex:=1 . In this instance you can simply put Cells(i,1) etc unless you are worried about getting the argument ordering wrong. Change the columnIndex as required.

Comment: Do I ever need to specify RowIndex or ColumnIndex? Or can I always leave them out?

Comment: In this instance you can always leave out in my opinion. Named arguments are good, especially with long argument lists, as it means you can pass arguments in a different order than expected, and miss optional parameters, and the function still knows what is what. With Cells there are only 2 required parameters. You could get them in the wrong order but if you don't think you will, then not specifying the name part of the argument makes it much more legible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would switch to XMLHTTP GET requests to retrieve the information you want faster.

The HTML doesn't lend itself to a nice way of selecting only the items of interest as you have discovered. Positional matching falls over when there aren't the same number of items on each page.

The pattern that is consistent, is that item names (`dt` tagged) and values (`dd` tagged) come in pairs. For example, `"Name"` comes with `"Town Hall"`; so you can collect the `dt` elements in one `nodeList`, and the `dd` in another; loop the first checking that the item names you want exist. The length of the list of item names will match the length of the list of associated values, so you only need loop the items and access the values `nodeList` using the same index as where your required item name was found.

---

**PROCESS:**

I store the sets of interest in an array, `sets`, which I read in from `Sheet1` column A. I loop that array, concatenating the current set number onto a base url constant to get the actual url for the lego set. The [XMLHTTP GET Request](https://codingislove.com/http-requests-excel-vba/) is issued against that url.

An helper function is employed, `GetHTMLDoc`, to process the request and return an `HTMLDocument` with the page html.

I use an additional helper function, `GetItemsInfo`, to retrieve the various items you want from the page HTML stored in the recently returned `HTMLDocument`. It creates a dictionary, `resultsDict`, whose keys are the items of interest i.e. `"Name","Theme"` etc.   These keys have an initial `vbNullstring` value, and if the key is found on the page, the value in the dictionary, for that key, is overwritten with the value found on the page.

The dictionaries of results for each page are stored in an array, `results`, which I later loop to write the results out to the page.

---

**TODO:**

1. You could develop this with some additional error handling. For example, when the GET request is unable to return the required HTML due to page not found, or to handle blank cells in column A between the start and end rows.
2. There is a free [SOAP based API](https://brickset.com/tools/webservices/v2) you could explore.I am not sure it offers all the available items of interest from an initial skim of the documentation.
3. Handle potential unwanted characters in return strings e.g. the `Â`  in the James Bond title which appears on writing to the sheet if not handled. In that case I used `Replace$(info(i).innerText, Chr$(194), vbNullString)`.

---

[**CSS SELECTORS:**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

I use the fact that each `dd` tag of interest is preceeded by a `dt` tag, within the parent `dl` tag of interest:

[image: example layout]

This means I can collect all the `dt` tags with a parent `dl` tag, using a CSS selector to target the page styling. I then loop over the returned `nodeList`, checking each node's `innerText` values against my dictionary keys. If they match (exists) then I know the item I want exists on the page. Given that there is a matching `dd` tag for each `dt` tag, within the parent element, I know that the value I want will be at the same index in the `nodeList` I can return by grabbing all the `dd` tags with parent tag `dl`. I can then overwrite the dictionary value with the found value.

I apply a CSS selector of `dl dt`, to return all elements with a `dt` tag having a parent `dl` tag. This selector is applied via the `.querySelectorAll` method of `HTMLDocument`. This returns a `nodeList` whose `.Length` can be traversed to access individual nodes by index, starting at 0. This is the `"titles"` nodeList - it contains each item name e.g `"Name","Theme"`etc.

**Example CSS query:**

[image]

A similar CSS query is used for the values, returning a `nodeList` which I refer to as `info`, using `dl dd`

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim i As Long, html As HTMLDocument, sets(), http As Object, results(), url As String
    Const BASE_URL As String = "https://brickset.com/sets/"
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Dim lastRow As Long: lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If lastRow < 5 Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf lastRow = 5 Then
            ReDim sets(1, 1): sets(1, 1) = .Range("A5").Value
        Else
            sets = .Range("A5:A" & lastRow).Value
        End If

        ReDim results(0 To UBound(sets, 1) - 1) 
        Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

        For i = LBound(sets, 1) To UBound(sets, 1)
            url = BASE_URL & sets(i, 1)
            Set html = GetHTMLDoc(http, url)
            Set results(i - 1) = GetItemsInfo(html)
        Next

        Dim headers()
        headers = Array("Set", "Name", "Theme", "Year released", "Pieces", "Minifigs")
        .Cells(4, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers

        For i = LBound(results) To UBound(results)
            .Cells(i + 5, 2).Resize(1, results(i).Count) = results(i).Items
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub

Public Function GetHTMLDoc(ByVal http As Object, ByVal url As String) As HTMLDocument
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument, sResponse As String
    With http
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        sResponse = StrConv(.responseBody, vbUnicode)
    End With       
    html.body.innerHTML = Mid$(sResponse, InStr(1, sResponse, "<!DOCTYPE "))   
    Set GetHTMLDoc = html
End Function

Public Function GetItemsInfo(ByVal html As HTMLDocument) As Object
    Dim titles As Object, info As Object, i As Long
    Dim resultsDict As Object
    Set resultsDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    resultsDict.Add "Name", vbNullString
    resultsDict.Add "Theme", vbNullString
    resultsDict.Add "Year released", vbNullString
    resultsDict.Add "Pieces", vbNullString
    resultsDict.Add "Minifigs", vbNullString

    With html
        Set titles = .querySelectorAll("dl dt")
        Set info = .querySelectorAll("dl dd")

        For i = 0 To titles.Length - 1
            If resultsDict.Exists(titles(i).innerText) Then
                resultsDict(titles(i).innerText) = Replace$(info(i).innerText, Chr$(194), vbNullString)
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Set GetItemsInfo = resultsDict
End Function
```

---

**RESULTS:**

[image: Results]

---

**References (VBE > Tools > References):**

1. Microsoft HTML Object Library

Comment: Thank you! This works exactly as I imagined! I will read through the code thoroughly to try to follow your line of thinking. Thank you very much!

Comment: And problems ask here and I will do my best to further explain.